# ArchLinux i3 font rendering issue on Chromium

Tags: chrome, text, i3

The font on Chromium's menu items is off-centered as seen below:

[image: Font rendering problem]

Only chromium has this issue (I've tested LibreOffice). The font used to be fine, but I believe I made a change somewhere that messed it all up. Any help figuring out how to fix the Chromium font would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, figured it out. I had changed my icon theme using lxappearance to `Numix` which caused this problem.